Bounded random walk joint distribution
Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. normally distributed random variable with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. Consider the bounded random walk $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, defined such that
\begin{align*}
   S_n = ((X_n + S_{n-1}) \land \overline{S}) \lor \underline{S},
\end{align*}
for $\underline{S} < \overline{S}$. Without the upper and lower constrains, $S_n$ is a random walk and its joint distribution is well known, but I cannot figure out the distribution when the bounds are imposed. Can you throw some ideas or point out to some helpful references?
